# What is the future of water treatment, and why we don't use enough purified sea and freshwater?

Tags: water, purification, distillation

I understand thermal and membrane distillation are very expensive and that slowed down their usage, but now we can bring 100% clean energy to power them. Except the set-up, the price of materials and the maintenance, I understand these other costs are not that heavy compare to energy from the grid ?
Many global companies have been building global purification centers but I'm thinking if local initiatives can be cheaper and interesting even in developed countries ?